# jar file not getting loaded after updating its classes

Tags: java

I had a jar file, it was working fine.
1. I unziped it.
2. decompiled the classes to java files.
3. updated a set of code.
4. Recomplied.
5. Created a jar from the bin folder containing 'META-INF' and 'org' structure.

This new jar file is somehow does not work or is not getting loaded, as its related classes are said to be missing.
What might be wrong?

Comment: Its related classes are probably missing. We don't know anything about the jar, anything about the code, anything about the error. How could we help?

Comment: Does the directory structure of the new jar match that of the original? Are the file names identical?